# SQL Distinct Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, error-handling

I have a SQL table that looks like:

```
email               User_id Category
Sarah.Ackland@bmo.com   44  Sent_Emails
Sarah.Ackland@bmo.com   44  Sent_Emails
Sarah.Ackland@bmo.com   44  Undeliverable
Adam.Bus@wraglaw.com    50  Sent_Emails
Adam.Duthie@bevn.com    56      Sent_Emails
```

and I am looking for an output that looks like:

```
email               User_id Category
Adam.Bushby@wraglaw.com 50  Sent_Emails
Adam.Duthie@bevn.com    56      Sent_Emails
```

Primarily I do not want to see any emails that were tagged as "undelivered". I tried using distinct but it still gives me the row with "Sarah.Ackland@bmo.com"

```
Appreciate your support.

Thanks
```

Comment: Do you want one, two or zero rows for Sarah?

Comment: I think it is still recommended to use DISTINCT as well, also Sent_Emails Category can have duplicates

Comment: @BrianDolan - I didn't want to see Sarah's record and therefore recommendations from Zsuzsa, Park Broom and Gordon Linoff all work perfect. Thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*
from sqltable t
where not exists (select 1
                  from sqltable t2
                  where t2.email = t.email and t2.category = 'Undeliverable'
                 );
```

Comment: You are too fast Gordon!

Comment: The performance of NOT IN is better than NOT EXISTS command's performance. However both solutions work fine.

Comment: @Zsuzsa . . . The performance issues are complicated.  Here is one read on the topic:  http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=24888.

Comment: Seems logical what it says, however I experienced performance issues with NOT EXISTS quite often.

Answer (score 3):

Try this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE User_id NOT IN (SELECT User_id FROM your_table WHERE Category = 'Undeliverable')
```

Comment: I think it is still recommended to use DISTINCT as well, also Sent_Emails Category can have duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE User_id NOT IN (SELECT User_id FROM your_table WHERE Category = 'Undeliverable')
```